# add DatePicker in the EditDialogColumn instead of plan textbox using react-md

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-design

I am using **react-md** (https://react-md.mlaursen.com/) in my project and I found a shortcoming of how to open a react-md **DatePicker** in the **EditDialogColumn** instead of just plain textbox.

I have a date as well in the react-md dataTables, so I wanted to show a datepicker instead of entering the date in the textbox which is showing from the react-md EditDialogColumn.

Below is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  DataTable,
  TableHeader,
  TableBody,
  TableRow,
  TableColumn,
  EditDialogColumn,
  DatePicker,
} from 'react-md';

const EditDialogExample = () => (
  <DataTable baseId="edit-dialog-example" fullWidth={false} className="data-tables__edit-table-example">
<TableBody>
      <TableRow>
        <TableColumn>
                    <EditDialogColumn
                      label="Type Start Date"
                      helpText="e.g. 2017-10-28"
                      onChange={val => {
                        this.handleInputChanges(
                          values[0],
                          val,
                          'tripStartDate',
                        );
                      }}
                    />
                  </TableColumn>
      </TableRow>
</TableBody>
  </DataTable>
);
```

I wanted to show below datepicker when click on above EditDialogColumn.

```
<DatePicker
      id="appointment-date-auto"
      label="Type Start Date"
      className="md-cell"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the below code and try

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {
      DataTable,
      TableHeader,
      TableBody,
      TableRow,
      TableColumn,
      EditDialogColumn,
      DatePicker,
    } from 'react-md';

    class EditDialogExample extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                showDatePicker: false
            }
            this.handleInputChanges = this.handleInputChanges.bind(this);
        }
        handleInputChanges(value, val, tempString){
            this.setState({
                showDatePicker: true
            })
        }

        renderDatePicker(){
            <DatePicker id="appointment-date-auto" label="Type Start Date" className="md-cell" />
        }
        render(){
            return(
              <div>
                <DataTable baseId="edit-dialog-example" fullWidth={false} className="data-tables__edit-table-example">
                <TableBody>
                      <TableRow>
                        <TableColumn>
                                    <EditDialogColumn
                                      label="Type Start Date"
                                      helpText="e.g. 2017-10-28"
                                      onChange={(val) => this.handleInputChanges(values[0], val, 'tripStartDate')}
                                    />
                                  </TableColumn>
                      </TableRow>
                </TableBody>
              </DataTable>
              {this.showDatePicker ? this.renderDatePicker() : ''}
            </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

I don't see onClick function and not sure whether EditDialogColumn allows onClick if so then try below

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {
      DataTable,
      TableHeader,
      TableBody,
      TableRow,
      TableColumn,
      EditDialogColumn,
      DatePicker,
    } from 'react-md';

    class EditDialogExample extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                showDatePicker: false
            }
            this.handleInputChanges = this.handleInputChanges.bind(this);
            this.handleonClick = this.handleonClick.bind(this);
        }
        handleInputChanges(value, val, tempString){

        }
        handleonClick(){
            this.setState({
                showDatePicker: true
            })
        }
        renderDatePicker(){
            <DatePicker id="appointment-date-auto" label="Type Start Date" className="md-cell" />
        }
        render(){
            return(
              <div>
                <DataTable baseId="edit-dialog-example" fullWidth={false} className="data-tables__edit-table-example">
                <TableBody>
                      <TableRow>
                        <TableColumn>
                                    <EditDialogColumn
                                      label="Type Start Date"
                                      helpText="e.g. 2017-10-28"
                                      onChange={(val) => this.handleInputChanges(values[0], val, 'tripStartDate')}
                                      onClick={this.handleonClick}
                                    />
                                  </TableColumn>
                      </TableRow>
                </TableBody>
              </DataTable>
              {this.showDatePicker ? this.renderDatePicker() : ''}
            </div>
            )
        }
    }
```